# Appium+Robot Framework: resource-ID element locator doesn't work as variable. It works as xpath variable

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework 4.1.1 and Appium-Python-Client 1.2.0 to run a test on an Android native app. I tried to use the Resource-ID locator (=welcome.pages.welcome.title) in different ways:

1. ${Welcome_element] =  welcome.pages.welcome.title
2. ${Welcome_element] =  id=welcome.pages.welcome.title
3. ${Welcome_element] =  id="welcome.pages.welcome.title"
4. ${Welcome_element] =  //android.widget.TextView[@id=welcome.pages.welcome.title"]
5. ${Welcome_element] =  //android.widget.TextView[@resource-id=welcome.pages.welcome.title"]

I get results:

1. Element locator 'welcome.pages.welcome.title' did not match any elements after 30 seconds
2. Element locator 'id=welcome.pages.welcome.title' did not match any elements after 30 seconds
3. Element locator 'id="welcome.pages.welcome.title"' did not match any elements after 30 seconds
4. Element locator '//android.widget.TextView[@id=welcome.pages.welcome.title"]' did not match any elements after 30 seconds
5. The keyword works as expected

So, I found the workaround. But how I can use just the ID value in the variable? The first case doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

try use the equal symbol near the variable

```
${Welcome_element]=  welcome.pages.welcome.title
```

and at least two space after...